# sympy division documentation terminology confusion

Tags: sympy

On the official sympy docs here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html#division
it says:

```
The function div() provides division of polynomials with remainder. 
That is, for polynomials f and g, it computes q and r, such that 
=⋅+ and deg()<. For polynomials in one variables with coefficients 
in a field, say, the rational numbers, q and r are uniquely defined 
this way:
```

Notice that it says `deg(r)<q`. Do they mean to say `deg(r)<deg(q)`?

Comment: The previous section on that page is much longer: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html#divisibility.  There's a lot of math theory that's beyond anything I studied (years ago).

Comment: Yes it should say `deg(r)<deg(q)`

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, If you are confident that this is the case, I'm happy to accept this as an answer. I realize this is a minor error, however if you know how to propose changes to the docs, I would like to do so.

Comment: If you want to suggest a change you can open a gituhb issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues. If you want to fix it yourself then you can open a pull request.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, thanks! I'll open an issue. Also, if you would like to answer this question, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accidentally put a bounty on this question. I am answering my own question here in an attempt to close the question.